# Datatable error in c#

Tags: c#

I used a datatable for fetching some data from mysql db,my error is

> not all code paths return a value

ie `return DS.Tables[0]` is unable to access inside a loop or if statement.How can i solve this issue?

```
public DataTable GetAlltheatredet()//I got error here//
{
    DataTable myalltheat = GetAllmytheatdet();
    foreach (DataRow drow1 in myalltheat.Rows)
    {
        usermsterid = drow1["UserMasterId"].ToString();
        if (usrmid == usermsterid)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                string connString = "Server=localhost;database=Mytable;uid=root;";
                string query = "SELECT * FROM `Mytable`.`Mydata`";
                MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                ma.Fill(DS);
                return DS.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately. The error is due to you not returning anything if flag isn't1

Comment: I formatted the code. If your code is different, please edit.

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense.  What are you trying to do?  The query to the database as nothing to do with the foreach loop where you are enumerating through the rows of a datatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have `if(flag==1) { ... return ... }` you need to add an `else` statement with either a `return` or a `throw new ...`

```
public DataTable GetAlltheatredet()//I got error here//
{
    DataTable myalltheat = GetAllmytheatdet();
    foreach (DataRow drow1 in myalltheat.Rows)
    {
        usermsterid = drow1["UserMasterId"].ToString();
        if (usrmid == usermsterid)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                string connString = "Server=localhost;database=Mytable;uid=root;";
                string query = "SELECT * FROM `Mytable`.`Mydata`";
                MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                ma.Fill(DS);
                return DS.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Flag isn't 1 and I don't know what to do");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that's a well known error, if your method that return DataType have any multi path blocks like if {} else {} or switch case, you should return something in every path of them.